# Client Side Ajax with jQuery reading a JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I'm trying to make a JavaScript that is fetching a JSON (IP DATA) and retrieves data from it (GEO IP) with AJAX and this is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var path_to_the_webservice = "http://www.pathtothescript.com/check.php";
    $.ajax({
        url: path_to_the_webservice,
        success: function(html)
        {
            if(html)
            {
                alert('3');
                $('#content').append(html);                         
            }
            else
            {
                alert('4');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and I get `alert(4)`, WHY?

Basically when you access `http://www.pathtothescript.com/check.php` from browser, retrieves a JSON that I have to parse with:

```
$.getJSON(path_to_the_json,
function(data) 
{
    $.each(data, function(i,item)
    {

    });
}
```

but I'm not sure how to make it.

The JSON looks like this `http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js`

Any help?

Comment: What is the output when you insert `console.log(html);` before the `if` statement, in the success handler?

Comment: Cross-domain-issues? Why do you name your parameter `html` if you expect a parsed JSON object?

Comment: Cross-domain-issues, it's like accessing this http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js with your ip , that's all

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by [Same origin policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy).

Try to use JSONP request:

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com?callback=?', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

---

**Handling the response from http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js**

```
// Actually we can send regular AJAX request to this domain
// since it sends header Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
// which allows cross-domain AJAX calls.
$.get('http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js', function(data) {

    console.log('Retrieved data:',
                data,
                'is type of', typeof data);

    // Now we have some functions to use:
    console.info('Some info:', geoip_country_name(),
                geoip_latitude(),
                geoip_longitude());
});​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/LYgTU/)

---

**UPDATE:**

In chat we found that my previous example works good in Google Chrome but doesn't work in Mozilla Firefox.
Though I played a little bit with it and found the solution:

```
// Actually we can send regular AJAX request to this domain
// since it sends header Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
// which allows cross-domain AJAX calls.
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        // Now we have some functions to use:
        alert(geoip_country_name() + ': (' 
              + geoip_latitude() + '; ' 
              + geoip_longitude() + ')');
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log('Error:', e);
    },
    contentType: 'application/javascript; charset=ISO-8859-1',
    dataType: 'script'
});
```

​

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/Yyuvu/)
Also I've set a charset accordingly to service [documentation](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/javascript).

Comment: i know what cross domain is but i'm just trying to access http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js and change 3-4 divs geo,ip...

Comment: @row: this URL returns JavaScript, not JSON.

Comment: http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js sends a header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` which allows cross-domain AJAX requests ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/LYgTU/)). So what's your problem?

Comment: so the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* matters a alot? uh? interesting ... but what about parsing the JSON? because this is not PHP with json -> array ..

Comment: Yes, this header matters. But if you're planning to use it in this way by your application, be careful. I've updated my answer to show how to deal with such kind of response. [Also good to read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i don't truly understand console.info console.log ... how can i alert them? it keep giving me empty data ...

Comment: You can use `alert()` instead of `console.log()`. And if it's giving you empty data, then check for JavaScript errors in JavaScript console and also be sure that server gives you a non-empty response.

Comment: Can you publish the URL which you're trying to access to get the data?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18379/discussion-between-row-minds-and-evgeniy-naydenov)